# Замeна Логина через RedBeanPHP

Tags: php, sql, redbeanphp

Вроде написано как надо, но данные в базе не изменяются

```
$data = $_POST;
    if ( isset($data['do_change']) ) {
        $user = R::findOne('users', 'login = ?', array($data['login']));
    if ( $user )
    {
        $user = R::load('user', $login); 
        $user->login = $data['login'];
        $user->login =  trim($data['newlogin']) ; 
        R::store( $user );
    }
}
```

newlogin это input в форме

Answer (score 0):

Сократил код и также вопрос, зачем вы задаете значение `$user->login` два раза?
На сколько я понимаю вы меняете Логин пользователя, следовательно запрос должен быть следующим:

```
$data = $_POST;
if ( isset($data['do_change']) and $user = R::findOne('users', 'login = ?', [$data['login']])) { 
    $user->login =  trim($data['newlogin']) ; 
    R::store($user);
}
```